# Why are some distributions not found using quantmod::getDividends()

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using quantmod v0.4.20 to look at distributions from High Interest Savings ETFs.
When I look at Yahoo I see that both of these ETFs made monthly distributions this year:

- Ninepoint High Interest Savings Fund ETF (NSAV.NE)
- Purpose High Interest Savings ETF (PSA.TO)

However, I can only see the distributions for PSA.TO

The ETF symbols are from Yahoo.

How do I get the distributions for NSAV.NE?

```
library("quantmod")

# Ninepoint High Interest Savings Fund ETF
# Distributions: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/NSAV.NE?p=NSAV.NE
div_nsav <- getDividends(
  Symbol = "NSAV.NE",
  src = "yahoo", 
  from = "2022-01-01",
  to = "2022-12-01")

# > div_nsav
# NSAV.NE.div


# Purpose High Interest Savings ETF
# Distributions: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/PSA.TO/
div_psa <- getDividends(
  Symbol = "PSA.TO",
  src = "yahoo", 
  from = "2022-01-01",
  to = "2022-12-01")

# > div_psa
# PSA.TO.div
# 2021-12-31      0.026
# 2022-01-28      0.021
# 2022-02-25      0.022
# 2022-03-30      0.035
# 2022-04-28      0.042
# 2022-05-30      0.058
# 2022-06-29      0.073
# 2022-07-28      0.093
# 2022-08-30      0.128
# 2022-09-29      0.139
# 2022-10-28      0.145
# 2022-11-29      0.179
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the historical data on yahoo finance and change the show option to dividends only, you can see that NSAV.NE has no dividend information on yahoo finance. If there is no data available on yahoo finance, you will not get any data via quantmod for the yahoo source.

If you need the dividend data, maybe the ETF fund website has it available.